# How to buffer and delay video during several seconds before preview with camera2 api

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have a working code for preview of video to a simple textureView. Now I want to buffer several seconds of video (hundreds of frames) before showing them on the textureView.

I do not want any conversion, I just want to take YUV_422_888 frames from the camera, put them in a large buffer, and after a given time (say 10s) start to show them in the same FPS they were recorded, e.g., 30 FPS. I want to do this continously.

I can find several examples and ideas of using ImageReader with RenderScript or OpenGL to manipulate the frames, with lots of code for converting between different formats. Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this in a simple way, without loads of conversion code?!

Comment: I am afraid you will find it easier to use standard compressed recording and playback than to manage hundreds of raw frames in memory

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? Is there a good way to buffer standard compressed recording and playback fast enough for, say, 25-30 fps? I need a live stream, but delayed in the range of 10 seconds.

Comment: What is not clear to you? I believe that it's quite straightforward to run MediaCodec to produce AVC frames, store them on disk, and play them continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Hundreds of frames takes a lot of memory.  At 720p, each YUV frame takes ~1.3 MB; at 1080p they take 3 MB each.

So 10 seconds of buffering will eat up 390 MB at 720p, 900 MB at 1080p.  That may cause problems for you on devices with lower amounts of memory.

You can use an ImageReader and ImageWriter pair, most likely, though selecting the right format is tricky.  YUV_420_888 may work, but technically TextureView is not guaranteed to accept them (but will on many, possibly all, devices).  So if YV12 is available, that may be a better bet.

Then create an ImageReader and ImageWriter with that format; for ImageWriter, give it a Surface from TextureView.  For ImageReader, pass its Surface to the camera device.

Then when a new Image becomes available from the ImageReader, acquire it and copy its contents (from all 3 planes) to your circular buffer.  Once your buffer gets full, start copying frames from it to your ImageWriter.

In theory, you could buffer frames in the ImageReader itself without a copy, but it has a maximum of around 64 frames it can queue up inside its queue.  That's nowhere near enough for 10 seconds.

Comment: Nice answer. I Will try a reader/writer pair. Are buffers from the camera to the reader hw-buffers? Is there any way to achieve zero-copy, (I guess not...) or lower the copy time/latency? It Will be a lot of shuffling of data :-)

Comment: Well, as you wrote, the tricky part seems to be to find the correct format. The ImageWriter seems to assume image format PRIVATE. Any Idea of how to force the Surface and ImageWriter to accept some YV12 or YUV_xxx format?

Currently I use the writer.queueInputImage(image) but it throws an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to attach an opaque image into a non-opaque ImageWriter, or vice versa.

Comment: 900 MB is far beyond what Android will allow an app to keep allocated, even with `android:largeheap="true"`. It is quite typical for a modern device to report *activityManager.getLargeMemoryClass() = 256 Mbyte*. I believe that [**Dianne Hackborn**'s statement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-ndk/lcnwzszrESo/wYpPk5BNC-QJ) *circa* 2010 is still valid: *There is no limit on allocations in the native heap*, but the platform if free to kill *such apps to keep everything running well*.

Comment: The NDK native_window methods are a touch more flexible than ImageWriter here (since there's a set format method), but definitely require a copy.  The most recent versions of Android have fixed up some issues with ImageWriter related to PRIVATE formats, but that won't help you much if you want to run on pre-P devices, unfortunately.